# @track not working in connectedCallback

Tags: lightning-web-components

In LWC, on the component load, I am fetching the latitude and longitude of the logged in user and trying to display it on the component. I have created two attributes named lat and lng and marked it with @track decorator so that whenever the value of these attributes is changed, the component will rerender automatically. I am setting the value of these attributes in connectedCallback, but the updated value is not getting reflected on the component. Below is the html and js files.

```
<template>
    <div class="slds-box">
        <div class="slds-text-heading--large">Weather Report - {lat} {lng}</div>
    </div>
</template>
```

```
import { LightningElement, track } from 'lwc';

export default class WeatherAppContainer extends LightningElement {
    @track lat;
    @track lng;
    connectedCallback() {
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
        }

        function showPosition(position) {
            console.log("position: ",position);
            console.log("position coords: ",position.coords);
            console.log("position coords lat: ",position.coords.latitude);
            this.lat = position.coords.latitude; 
            this.lng = position.coords.longitude; 
            console.log("lat: ",this.lat);
            console.log("lng: ",this.lng);
        }
    }

}
```

The console "position coords lat" prints the value correctly, but the next console statment does not get printed. I am guessing that we cannot use this keyword in the connectedCallback. Any pointers how to solve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

`this` is quite funny in javascript, in `connectedCallback` `this` refers to component, but in `showPosition` as its async method, `this` is undefined, and thus you cannot set lat and long

Usually, for this scenario, we pass the current component reference `this` to showPosition method like one [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/268143/19118). But as per Mozilla document , you cant pass custom parameter to [getCurrentPositionCallback](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/getCurrentPosition)

You have to use [fatArrow function](https://www.sitepoint.com/es6-arrow-functions-new-fat-concise-syntax-javascript/) for `getCurrentPositionCallback`.

Thus your JS code will be:

```
import { LightningElement, track, api } from 'lwc';

export default class App extends LightningElement {
    @track lat;
    @track lng;
    connectedCallback() {
        console.log('Connected callback called'+ navigator.geolocation);
        console.log(JSON.stringify(navigator.geolocation));
        let myComponent = this;
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position)=>{
            console.log("position: ",position);
            console.log("position coords: ",position.coords);
            console.log("position coords lat: ",position.coords.latitude);
            myComponent.lat = position.coords.latitude; 
            myComponent.lng = position.coords.longitude; 
            console.log("lat: ",myComponent.lat);
            console.log("lng: ",myComponent.lng);
            });
        }


    }


}
```

Playground Link : https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/htbBevIZr/2/edit

Comment: Thanks Pranay. Do you see any problem with below code:

Comment: connectedCallback() {
        let self = this;
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
        }
        function showPosition(position) {
            self.lat = position.coords.latitude; 
            self.lng = position.coords.longitude; 
        }
    }

Comment: @RaviDuttSharma that will do. Fat Arrow functions are the elegant way to write inner function.

Comment: window.myThis = this;   This worked for me.

Comment: Worked! Lifesaver!

Answer (score 4):

The problem lies with how `this` behaves in JavaScript. I strongly recommend reading https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

As to fixing your code, this one line change does the trick:

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition.bind(this));
```

You can read about `bind`at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

Comment: +1, There is always an elegant way in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

**this** will be window object as functions in navigator returns promises - which makes it async methods/functions. I already answered this here:
[LWC property is not reactive](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/268140/lwc-property-is-not-reactive)

However I am putting it here again:

This pitfall is quite common for salesforce developers working on Javascript. Set-Interval actually changes the context of **this** to window as functions like setInterval, setTimeout etc are async functions and hence these functions run after the main thread has finished processing. This can be addressed by any of 2 options:

1. Lexical Scoping - old fashioned (pls do a google search for understanding)
2. Arrow functions - Modern javascript. (PFB)

Just change the callback function from:

```
setInterval(function(){}, 500);
```

To

```
setInterval(() => {}, 500);
```

For simple understanding, Arrow functions don't have their own scope because of which it takes the scope of parent object.

There are many other advantages of arrow functions. 
Further read: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions