# LWC emp API track field is not rendering

Tags: lightning-web-components, change-data-capture, empapi

I am trying with small example of emp API, everything works fine I am able to subscribe and unsubscribe, however, the response of CDC not printing in the UI for some reason.

May I am missing a small thing here.

```
<template>
    <lightning-card title="EmpApi Example" icon-name="custom:custom14">
        <div class="slds-m-around_medium">
            <p>Use the buttons below to subscribe and unsubscribe to a streaming channel!</p>
            <lightning-input label="Channel Name" value={channelName}
                onchange={handleChannelName}></lightning-input>
            <lightning-button variant="success" label="Subscribe" title="Subscribe"
                onclick={handleSubscribe} disabled={isSubscribeDisabled}
                class="slds-m-left_x-small"></lightning-button>
            <lightning-button variant="destructive" label="Unsubscribe" title="Unsubscribe"
                onclick={handleUnsubscribe} disabled={isUnsubscribeDisabled}
                class="slds-m-left_x-small"></lightning-button>

        </div>
        {eventresponse}
        {payload}

    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

JS:

```
import { LightningElement,track  } from 'lwc';
import { subscribe, unsubscribe, onError, setDebugFlag, isEmpEnabled } from 'lightning/empApi';

export default class LwcEmpapi extends LightningElement {
    @track channelName = '/event/ContactChangeEvent';
    @track isSubscribeDisabled = false;
    @track isUnsubscribeDisabled = !this.isSubscribeDisabled;
    @track payload;
    subscription = {};

    // Tracks changes to channelName text field
    handleChannelName(event) {
        this.channelName = event.target.value;
    }

    // Handles subscribe button click
    handleSubscribe() {
        // Callback invoked whenever a new event message is received
        const messageCallback = function(response) {
            console.log('New message received : ', JSON.stringify(response));
            this.payload = JSON.stringify(response);
            console.log('this.payload: '+this.payload);
            // Response contains the payload of the new message received
        };

        // Invoke subscribe method of empApi. Pass reference to messageCallback
        subscribe(this.channelName, -1, messageCallback).then(response => {
            // Response contains the subscription information on successful subscribe call
            console.log('Successfully subscribed to : ', JSON.stringify(response.channel));
            this.subscription = response;
            this.toggleSubscribeButton(true);
        });
    }

    get eventresponse(){
        return this.payload;
    }

    // Handles unsubscribe button click
    handleUnsubscribe() {
        this.toggleSubscribeButton(false);

        // Invoke unsubscribe method of empApi
        unsubscribe(this.subscription, response => {
            console.log('unsubscribe() response: ', JSON.stringify(response));
            // Response is true for successful unsubscribe
        });
    }

    toggleSubscribeButton(enableSubscribe) {
        this.isSubscribeDisabled = enableSubscribe;
        this.isUnsubscribeDisabled = !enableSubscribe;
    }

    registerErrorListener() {
        // Invoke onError empApi method
        onError(error => {
            console.log('Received error from server: ', JSON.stringify(error));
            // Error contains the server-side error
        });
    }
}
```

Log:

[image]

Comment: Can you move {payload}, below closure of lightning-card?

Comment: I just tried it, no change the output:(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thats because of lexical scoping. `this` will refer to the emp channel and not class. To get the scope of Class in callback, you should use arrow function (as it does not have its own scope)

Change `messageCallback` to:

```
const messageCallback = (response) => {
        console.log('New message received : ', JSON.stringify(response));
        this.payload = JSON.stringify(response);
        console.log('this.payload: ' + this.payload);
        // Response contains the payload of the new message received
    };
```

Comment: Yes, you are right. Now  I remember, I had similar issue with lexical scope. https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/268140/lwc-property-is-not-reactive

Comment: Even when we keep double arrow, if we try to call an apex method from that scope, it fails and reload the page,  https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/314515/firing-dispatch-event-or-an-apex-call-from-streaming-api-callback-fails-in-lwc